# Wordpress Contact form breaking out of div

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, forms

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/F7LzT/1/) jsfiddle for some reason when I extend the message box to the right and down the gray div that holds the elements does not extend with it. How can I make it so when the user enlarges the message box the gray element div scales with it?

This is the container info I copied from chrome:

```
<div class="one_third last">
    <div class="framed_box rounded">
        <div class="framed_box_content" style="height:500px;">

<h3 style="text-align: center;">Request a Quote</h3>

            <div class="quote" style="font-size: 11px; padding: 0 0 0 15px; _padding: 0;">
                <div class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f3658-p3891-o1">
                    <form action="/#wpcf7-f3658-p3891-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div style="display: none;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="3658">
                            <br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.6">
                            <br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="">
                            <br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f3658-p3891-o1">
                            <br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="691674e2bf">
                        </div>
                        <p>Name (required) <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="30" maxlength="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
                            <br>Email (required) <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="30" maxlength="60" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
                            <br>Phone (required) <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="30" maxlength="12" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
                            <br>Zip (required) <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-zip"><input type="text" name="your-zip" value="" size="30" maxlength="5" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
                            <br>I am Interested in (Check all that Apply):
                            <br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tub-prod"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="tub-prod[]" value="Walk In Bathtubs">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Walk In Bathtubs</span></span>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                            <br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap shower-prod"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="shower-prod[]" value="Walk In Showers">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Walk In Showers</span></span>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                            <br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap install-needed"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="install-needed[]" value="Renovations/Remodeling">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Renovations/Remodeling</span></span>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                            <br>Message
                            <br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="28" rows="1" maxlength="200" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> 
                            <br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_captcha_challenge_captcha-146" value="1307789336">
                            <img class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-captchac wpcf7-captcha-captcha-146" width="60" height="20" alt="captcha" src="http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_captcha/1307789336.png">
                            <br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap captcha-146"><input type="text" name="captcha-146" value="" size="28" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-captchar" aria-invalid="false"></span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit Request" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit button">
                            <img class="ajax-loader" src="http://test.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;">
                        </p>
                        <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearboth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to specify the `position:absolute` at `.rounded`

```
  .rounded, .rounded .framed_box_content {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

I've noticed your static `height value of 500px` so just change that to `height:auto` then your all good.I have updated the fiddle too.
here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7LzT/4/)

Comment: the code's kinda messy, lemme check what i can do for the textarea

Comment: also notice that the border disappears after setting position to absolue

Comment: for the borders just add `border: 1px solid rgba(197, 188, 188, 0.8);` to the same `.rounded` class or you can define your own.

Comment: I think your problem is solved now. check the updated JSFiddle.

Comment: It works but it still does not perform as intended it will not allow the content below it to scale. I think I might just put these in a lightbox or just make it a text field instead.